# Preventing cursor flickering in ncurses applications

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I recently wrote an application in ncurses. In most of it, the cursor is disabled, but one part of it includes an editor (using forms), and the cursor is enabled for this (with visibility 2).

I have some different panes (really multiple windows, composing the screen) in the application, including a status bar at the bottom, and whenever the row changes in one window, I update the status bar (part of a different window) to reflect the new line number. The windows are all non-overlapping.

Occasionally, but not always, I notice the cursor briefly visible at the end of the repainted window in the status bar. For the most part, I batch up screen updates using `wnoutrefresh`, and this is always the case when updating the status bar. The window where the cursor should be is a pad, and `doupdate()` is only called when the pad is updated.

Ideally, I would only notice the cursor moving around the window where it is originally, and the side-effects of updating other windows would not cause the cursor to be briefly visible there, causing a brief, but distracting, flash. I'm a bit stuck on why this is happening currently and how I could prevent it, given all the window updates are being batched in the manner described above. To experiment, I tried both:

- saving the original cursor position prior to updating the status bar and re-enabling it after, so that the cursor position is restored after that window is updated
- disabling the cursor before updating the status bar and re-enabling it after. I didn't really expect this to work, since the status bar is updated using `wnoutrefresh` already, and indeed it doesn't make any difference.

I thought the first approach would work, as there is another "bug" currently where if the status bar is updated in the background and `doupdate()` is called immediately, the cursor will be left at the end of the new text there until something happens in the window where the cursor is to cause the cursor to move back to the right place. This behavior makes sense to me, which is why I'm a bit puzzled at the different behavior of the other case.

Is there anything else I could do to ensure the cursor doesn't get moved around like this? I suppose one way would be writing to a window without moving the cursor, but not sure if that is the best/only way.

Comment: You need to post a [mre]. It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong just from a description like this.

Comment: The cursor's going to move around the screen, ending up on (a) the last updated location or (b) the current position in a window used for input, e.g., `wgetch`.  It's usually possible to hide the cursor to eliminate issues with (a), but (b) is expected.

Comment: @ThomasDickey To clarify, I want the cursor to stay in the input field, and not move around while writing text to other windows (or at least have the appearance of doing so).  I'm also not calling `wgetch` directly, instead I poll multiple file descriptors, since I need to listen for other stuff at the same time, and only call `wgetch` if poll returns activity from STDIN. Also, most of the time, I don't see any flickering, it's maybe 10-20% of the time I notice this.

Comment: You could force the cursor to return to the input field by calling wgetch() with a short timeout.   Since you're doing screen updates which may not see any input for "a while" then the cursor will temporarily sit on the latest update.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I tried that out and interestingly, I still seem to see the flickering occasionally/about the same frequency. After updating that status line, I do `timeout(0)`, getch, ungetch if c was not ERR, then `timeout(-1)`.